# How to properly run two while loops in asyncio code with executor pools?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have two functions that I want to run concurrently.
A heartbeat function, that is executes a simple while loop.
and then another function which is the meat of the script, that's also in a while loop.

While the heartbeat functions marches along, the meat and potatoes function ruins once and never loops...

I'm using asyncio and executor pools to accomplish my goals of having two functions (loops) running simulutaneously.

Also how do I get errors/exception to show while using executor pools, I cant see any errors....

here's the code:

```
   import lib.myFunctions
   import asyncio
   import oandapy       

   fmc = lib.myFunctions.FmcMixin()

   def meatAndPotatoes(currency_pair=sys.argv[1],
        time_compression=sys.argv[2],sleep_time=sys.argv[3]):
        while True:
           try:
             something = oanda.get_history()
             if (something):
                  print("niceeee")
             else:
                  print("ok cool")
           except:
             sleep(sleep_time)



  if __name__ == "__main__":
      executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(2)
      loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
      asyncio.async(loop.run_in_executor(executor, meatAndPotatoes))
      scriptName = str(sys.argv[1]+"/"+sys.argv[2]+"/")
      asyncio.async(loop.run_in_executor(executor, \
         fmc.heartbeatFunction(scriptName)))
      loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: If both of your functions need to run in an `Executor`, and you're not actually using any non-blocking I/O, you probably shouldn't be using `asyncio`. You might as well just use `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` directly.

Comment: ahhh the futures stuff is throwing me off because i dont need to return anything from these functions its mostly input and output to remote services....can you pass any efficent references on concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor?